# Advantages of pageable memory

Tags: linux, memory, performance

While installing a Nessus product I came up with the following statement,

> Generally, a Nessus Agent uses 40 MB of RAM (all pageable).

Here, What they tried to mean by ***all pageable*** ? As I understand from the paragraph of the statement that they were trying to mean that the process will not hog much memory.

So my question is how pageable memory improve the performance [or reduce performance hogging] or how pageable memory left low memory footprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it can be paged out, if necessary — either to swap, or to the original executable (and libraries).

The advantage is that when the agent isn’t doing anything, it doesn’t need to consume any physical RAM at all, so it has hardly any footprint on the system. Since [the authors also claim](https://docs.tenable.com/generalrequirements/Content/NessusAgentHardwareRequirements.htm) that the agent “uses almost no CPU while idle”, that means that when it’s idle its presence shouldn’t be felt at all.

This isn’t really anything particularly exciting for most applications, since most code and allocated memory is pageable anyway.

Comment: I think the bigger thing here is that they're not using anything to prevent that memory from being pageable, like calling `mlock()` on it.  There are a number of security related applications that explicitly lock all of their allocations into RAM (making them non-pageable) as a means of defense against memory-based DoS attacks.

Comment: @Austin hence “most applications”. I agree some would arrange for their memory to not be pageable (although that’s to avoid having secrets stored on disk, not to avoid denials of service, AFAIK), but I wouldn’t expect a Nessus agent to do so, or most applications for that matter.